# Whats wrong with this UITableView deletion code?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am receiving the error below from the following code, please can you tell me what my problem is.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        id object = [[[self cdArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
        [[self cdArray] removeObject:object];
        [[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:object];
        [self refreshArray];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"\n%s\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [error description]);
        }
        [[self tableView] deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
}

- (void) refreshArray {
    if ([self cdArray] == nil) {
        [self setCdArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];
    }
    [cdArray removeAllObjects];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];    
    for (CDImage *image in fetchedObjects) {
        [cdArray addObject:image];
    }
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call

```
[self refreshArray];
```

until after you have committed your delete here,

```
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"\n%s\n%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, [error description]);
}
```

You should switch the lines.

Comment: It seems like the delete is not happening. Can you verify the number of objects being returned during the fetch in `refreshArray`?